# Is it possible to observe arrays within arrays using @each?

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller that contains an array of "things".  Within each of these things is an array of "subthings".  I'd like to create a computed property that contains all subthings in all things (a flattened array of subthings).

My computed property depends on `things.@each.subthings.length`.  I find that if I **set** the `subthings` property of a thing, my computed property is updated.  However if I call `pushObjects` to add new data to my **existing** `subthings` array, my computed property does not update.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rharper/pDQeT/4/) to demonstrate.  The code is as follows:

```
App = Em.Application.create({});

App.controller = Em.Object.create({
    things: [
        Em.Object.create({subthings:[]}),
        Em.Object.create({subthings:[]}),
        Em.Object.create({subthings:[]})        
    ],

    allSubThings : function() {
        var things = this.get('things');
        var results = [];
        things.forEach( function(thing)  {
            results.pushObjects( thing.get('subthings') );
        });
        return results;
    }.property('things.@each.subthings.length').cacheable()        
});


setTimeout(function() {
    var things = App.controller.get('things');
    // This works:
    things.objectAt(0).set('subthings',[1,2,3]);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    var things = App.controller.get('things');
    // This does not:
    things.objectAt(1).get('subthings').pushObjects([1,2,3]);
}, 2000);
```

​
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another `@each` to the property list `.property('things.@each.subthings.@each.length')`

http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/pDQeT/3/

Comment: That works well, thanks!  Maybe I don't quite understand what @each is doing here.  It appears that your solution is observing the length property of each element of the "subthings" array, not the length of the subthings array itself.

Comment: From Ember docs: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/   "Note that @each only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms like todos.@each.owner.name or todos.@each.owner.@each.name