# Ember nested array property observable

Tags: ember.js

When setting property observable on a nested array in ember my property isn't notified.

```
size: function(){
      var result = "no size";

      this.get('data.properties').forEach(function (g) {
        if (g.group == "style") {
            g.items.forEach(function (p) {
                if (p.id == 'size') result = p.computedValue();
            });
        }
      });

    console.log(result);

    return result;
}.property('data.properties.@each.items.@each.value')
```

In this SO accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9381152/2068563
it says that this should work.

But for me the propurty is only computed at init.
here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorvan/eVWfj/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, the solution is to link computed properties updated by observable to bubble up the event like this:

```
App.groupObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    group: "style",
    name: "Style",
    _changed: 0,
    changed: function (key, value) {
        if (value) {
            this.set('_changed', value);
        }
        return this.get('_changed');
    }.property(),
    itemChanged: function () {
        this.set('changed', +new Date());
        console.log('item changed!');
    }.observes('items.@each.val'),

    items: []
});

App.itemObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    _val: 6,
    id: null,
    name: null,
    group: null,
    fieldType: null,
    val: function (key, value) {
        if (value) {
            this.set('_val', value);
        }

        return this.get('_val');
    }.property(),
    computedValue: function () {
        return this.val;
    }
});
```

Basically, the grouo object listens to any action on the item's val property and updates his own changed property. this way i can do:

```
size: function(){
      var result = "no size";

      this.get('data.properties').forEach(function (g) {
        if (g.group == "style") {
            g.items.forEach(function (p) {
                if (p.id == 'size') result = p.computedValue();
            });
        }
      });

    console.log(result);

    return result;
}.property('data.properties.@each.changed')
```

I guess my first miastake was to think ember was magically going to pickup changes on my nested objects.

I also thought that linking computed properties would work, which obviously didnt! (Why?)

the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorvan/LEyCD/

### EDIT

Since this was pretty long to implement on each object I created my own object with observable based on a selector.

```
    App.changeAwareArray = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
    init: function () {

        this.set('content', []);
        this._super();
        if (!this.get('changeSelector')) this.set('changeSelector', '_changed');

        this.addObserver('content.@each.' + this.get('changeSelector'), this.handleChange);
    },
        _changed: null,
    handleChange: function () {
        this.set('_changed', +new Date());
    }
});

App.changeAwareObject = Ember.Object.extend({
init: function () {
        this._super();
        if (!this.get('changeSelector')) this.set('changeSelector', '_changed');

        this.addObserver(this.get('changeSelector'), this.handleChange);
    },
        _changed: null,
    changed: function (key, value) {
        if (value) {
            this.set('_changed', value);
        }
        return this.get('_changed');
    }.property(),
    handleChange: function () {
        this.set('_changed', +new Date());
    }
});
```

Now you can chain them to observe them:

```
    App.groupObj = App.changeAwareObject.extend({
    changeSelector:'items._changed',
    group: "style",
    name: "Style",
    items: App.changeAwareArray.create()
});

App.itemObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    _val: 6,
    _changed: null,
    id: null,
    name: null,
    group: null,
    fieldType: null,
    val: function (key, value) {
        if (value) {
            this.set('_val', value);
            this.set('_changed', +new Date());
        }
        return this.get('_val');
    }.property(),
    computedValue: function () {
        return this.val;
    }
});
```

And get the data in your view/controller:

```
    App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function () {
        this._super();
        //populate the Array
        this.data.properties.pushObject(createData());
    },
    elementId: "test",
    size: function () {
        var result = "no size";

        this.get('data.properties').forEach(function (g) {
            if (g.group == "style") {
                g.items.forEach(function (p) {
                    if (p.id == 'size') result = p.computedValue();
                });
            }
        });

        return result;
    }.property('data.properties._changed'),
    offset: function () {
        var result = "no offset";

        this.get('data.properties').forEach(function (g) {
            if (g.group == "style") {
                g.items.forEach(function (p) {
                    if (p.id == 'offset') result = p.computedValue();
                });
            }
        });

        return result;
    }.property('data.properties._changed'),
    data:{
        name: "base",
        properties: App.changeAwareArray.create()
    }
});
```

you can find a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorvan/VRVac/